# Book for Core Animation for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-animation, ios4

I want to learn "Core Animation" for the **iOS** not for the Mac.

Two books exist:

PragProg: Core Animation

AW: Core Animation Simplified

Have you read one of them (or both)? do you have a recommendation?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really a good fit for SO. All you are going to get are opinions.

Comment: @Abizern It looks like it was OK to ask it last year.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the book from Bill Dudney is not that good.
Most of the book is relating to the Mac and it was written in 2008. The emphasis on iPhone is not that present and I would buy that one. Unfortunately there is not really an alternative at the moment besides reading the doc or having a look on more recent tutorials. Well, the developer videos from the WWDC are nice.. they provide a good first glance on CA

Answer (score 2):

I have both the Bill Dudney book (Pragmatic) the Marcus Zarra/Matt Long (Addison Wesley) book.

I agree with the other poster that the Dudney book is pretty  thin on iOS Core Animation. It's still worth a read, though.

The Marcus Zarra/Matt Long Core Animation Book from Addison Wesley has a little more iOS stuff in it.

The layer-based animation (both implicit and explicit) in both books is very useful. Dudney's book goes into a lot of Mac-specific CA, and has very little on iOS-specific CA. It does still have useful information in it however.

I don't think there's a really good book yet that covers iOS Core Animation. There have been lots of changes lately - specifically the new block-based UIView animations. For simple animations, those are the way to go, and I haven't seen a book that covers that approach yet.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read either of the books you suggest.

I've read ["Core Animation for Mac OS X and the iPhone" by Bill Dudney](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356107), and think that's a pretty good book.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to start reading ["Graphics and Animation on iOS: A Beginner's Guide to Core Graphics and Core Animation"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020356.do)..

will add review after going through it.

Comment: It was very Basic , NOt what i was looking for :)